# DNS server address change

Tags: terminal

I’m new to editing in Terminal on Raspberry Pi4.  I have the most uptodate version.

How do I open /etc/dhcpcd.conf so I can add server addresses?

I’m sure this a very basic question, but I can’t get anything than non-editable lines.

Comment: `sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf` or `sudo vi /etc/dhcpcd.conf`, nano is the easier to use option of the 2. `Sudo` is to elevate your user to edit files as root as you are editing files in the location `/etc` which are usually system configurations.

Comment: Thank you!  I had no idea the term sudo was required.

Comment: @CraftyB you should post that as an actual answer.

Comment: You're welcome, please hit the up arrow / tick next to the answer to mark it as correct. I have flagged the answer you created as it was meant to be a comment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sudo nano /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

or

```
sudo vi /etc/dhcpcd.conf
```

nano is the easier text editor to use of the 2

"Sudo" is to elevate your user to edit files as root as you are editing files in the location "/etc" which are usually system configurations.